# htaccess URL rewrite for both php and pdf files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I know this comes up often on SO but I'm struggling to understand bits of it and hoping somebody can help.

I need to take the following:
http://www.xyz.com/news.room/showstory.php?storyid=123456
and create
http://www.xyz.com/newsroom/123456

http://www.xyz.com/news.room/
and create
http://www.xyz.com/newsroom/

http://www.xyz.com/files/pdf/uk/Wk51.pdf
and create
http://www.xyz.com/newsroom/convert/Wk51

in addition xyz.co.uk and xyz.org should also be rewritten to xyz.com and all should report back to the search engines as permanent redirects

I'm trying to do this in a htaccess file, that also has a standard CodeIgniter rewrite rule in it to remove the query strings.

Can anyone help me?  I've tried several things but can't get anything that works for everything! Also i've spent five hours on this and am slowly pulling my hair out!

Any help, pointing in the right direction etc.. would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#redirect any domain other than example.com, to example.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^newsroom/$ /news.room/

RewriteRule ^newsroom/([0-9]+)$ /news.room/showstory.php?storyid=$1

RewriteRule ^newsroom/convert/([^/]+)$ /files/pdf/uk/$1.pdf
```

Comment: Gerben, sorry for the delay in replying, I got pulled away and didn't get back to my desk.  So that I understand this, am I right in assuming that after the RewriteRule part ... the next section is what it needs to become, followed by the original part.  I understand the $1 theory, but am I right in saying that [^/]+ means any character in here plus the $1 variable?

Comment: No, the first part after `RewriteRule` is the pattern you want to match. After that comes what you want to rewrite it to. $0 is the entire match; $1 is the part between the first set of parentheses, $2 the second etc.. Not that the rewrites are internal, so the rewritten url is uses to by apache to retrieve the resource, but is not visible in the users address-bar. `[^/]` means any character except the `/`; the plus means one of more of these characters.

Comment: Ah right so something like RewriteRule ^abc/pdf/+$ /xyz/2012/publications/$1.pdf  would rewrite 123.com/xyz/2012/publications/Month12.pdf to 123.com/abc/pdf/Month12.pdf?   How would you remove the word 'month' from the filename?

Comment: You need to use `RewriteRule ^abc/pdf/(.+)$ /xyz/2012/publications/$1.pdf` (note the parentheses and the dot before the plus). Also in the final url you need to remove the `.pdf` because the rule adds that. So with this rule a request for `example.com/abc/pdf/Month12` will make Apache use `example.com/xyz/2012/publications/Month12.pdf` internally. To remove the Month part you could use `RewriteRule ^abc/pdf/([0-9]+)$ /xyz/2012/publications/Month$1.pdf`